# How to plot graphs in tikz using large number of data points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I have my experimental data in a tabular form in word document format. I want to plot the data points using tikz. How to export the data points from `data.doc` to tikz plot? These are the data points. I want to plot `(A,B);(A,C);(A,D);(A,E);(A,F).`

```
A       B   C   D   E   F
0.05    5   9   19  7   10
0.10    8   9   19  9   10
0.15    11  9   19  10  10
0.20    12  9   19  10  19
0.25    14  9   19  11  19
0.30    15  9   19  11  11
0.35    15  9   19  11  11
0.40    16  9   19  11  19
0.45    17  9   19  11  12
0.50    17  9   19  11  12
```

I have plotted one graph manually using the `coordinates{()()...}` option in tikz, but for large number of data points it is cumbersome. I want to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Have a look at `pgfplots`, it can do all of this automatically. What do you mean `data.doc`? As in, the old Microsoft Word format? That will surely not work, you need to save in a plain-text format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{
A       B   C   D   E   F
0.05    5   9   19  7   10
0.10    8   9   19  9   10
0.15    11  9   19  10  10
0.20    12  9   19  10  19
0.25    14  9   19  11  19
0.30    15  9   19  11  11
0.35    15  9   19  11  11
0.40    16  9   19  11  19
0.45    17  9   19  11  12
0.50    17  9   19  11  12
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{B,...,F}{
  \addplot+[] table[x=A,y=#1] {\mytable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add legend to these plots?

Comment: You can take it from here with the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: There should be `five graphs`, but here I found `six` graphs. I think the lower one is `(A,A)`. This has to be removed.

Comment: I got it by replacing `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{A,...,F}` with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{B,...,F}`.

Comment: Can it be possible to load the values from a file without copying and pasting the data points in the main `.tex` file. As I need to include lot of plots, this will unnecessarily make my tex file extra lengthy?

Comment: @LitunJohn Yes, you can replace `\mytable` with the file name (a txt or csv or whatever but not a doc file).

Comment: How to edit the color settings of the graphs?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest an easier method. Store them in .dat file and refer to their rows and columns while plotting them. This prevents clutter in your tex file. However, plotting multiple curves might require an equal number of .dat files, one to store each set of data points.